# MySQL order by date before selecting

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get all topics along with the last comment in each topic. I've tried a couple of different sql statements, which haven't been working out.

```
SELECT 
    a.*, 
    b.*, 
    c.*, 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE comment_topic_id = a.topic_id) AS count
FROM topics AS a 
LEFT JOIN categories AS b ON a.topic_category = b.category_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM comments
    ORDER BY comment_date DESC
) AS c ON a.topic_id = c.comment_topic_id
WHERE b.category_id = '1' AND b.category_permission <= '2'
ORDER BY a.topic_created ASC
```

The above code will generate a result for each comment instead of the most recent. 
Any help is appreciated, I can provide images to illustrate the database and table structures

Comment: why use a dubquery for last left join? move "order by" comment_date at the end of main query e comments table goes in left join in the main

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I followed, could you show in code?

Comment: FROM topics AS a 
LEFT JOIN categories AS b ON a.topic_category = b.category_id
LEFT JOIN comments as c
ON a.topic_id = c.comment_topic_id ...... order by comment_date DESC

Comment: Well, again that returns 1 row for each comment instead of 1 row for each topic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the alias of your count because count is a reserved word.

Try this:

**EDIT**

```
SELECT 
    a.*, 
    b.*, 
    co.*, 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE comment_topic_id = a.topic_id) AS tot_comment
FROM topics AS a 
JOIN categories AS b ON a.topic_category = b.category_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM comments c
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 'NEXT'
        FROM comments c2
        WHERE c2.comment_topic_id = c.comment_topic_id
        AND c2.comment_date > c.comment_date
    )
) AS co ON a.topic_id = co.comment_topic_id
WHERE b.category_id = '1' AND b.category_permission <= '2'
ORDER BY a.topic_created ASC
```

Comment: Returns #1054 - Unknown column 'a.topic_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: @user3067688: I try to create 3 dummy tables to execute your query. Give the 10 mins.

Comment: Okay, sure np. take your time!

Comment: @user3067688: in select fields which info of your comments you want to show? All fields?

Comment: The only fields I need to select from the comments table are the comment_username and comment_date, this way I can see when the last comment was made and by which user.

Comment: @user3067688: Check now ;) I try on my pc, now SqlFiddle is down

Comment: oh my god, I think it works... let me double check, one moment.

Comment: @user3067688: Before my fault was: in subquery in FROM clause I can't use refer with other tables at the same level.

Comment: Awesome!! it works! Thanks so much. But I need to understand the query you shared. How does the WHERE NOT EXISTS part work?

Comment: I use NOT EXISTS because I've selected only LAST comments. You can read it in this way: Fixed a topic, give me a comment where not exists any comments where its date is greater than of mine.

Comment: @user3067688: Because you are new. You can upvote the answer (clicking on up arrow), if you want obviously ;)

Comment: Already tried but it says I need 15 reputation points... I only have 8 ._.

Comment: @user3067688: Ok, don't worry. Have a nice day ;)